# Problem with network location provider on Android 9 emulator

Tags: geolocation, location-services

I am using Android 9 to debug a location-related application. I set the location via telnet "geo fix", and check via "adb shell dumpsys location" and directly in the app. The problem is network location (gps and passive are always correct). The network location very often points to Google headquarters in San Francisco. The problem occurs when the app switches to running in the background, when it uses an inaccurate location. How to fix it? I am using production emulator (without root).